# How to select rows where values are present in only 2 columns from a data frame

Tags: r, na

I have a long data frame with a lot of `NA`'s.

I would like to find the ratio of the value of Column A and Column D.
How do I only select the rows where there's data present in both Column A and Column D?

As an example, in this image I want to only compare the values of rows 2,4,6 for Columns A and D.

[image: Example screenshot]

I can use `na.omit` on each row, but I'm not sure how to ask R to find the rows where data is present in both columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options using **base** R.

Using `is.na()`:

```r
df[!is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$D), ]
#     A   B     C   D
# 1 432  15 54654 432
# 2 321  NA  4534 324
# 3 123 432  6543  75
```

Using `complete.cases()`:

```r
df[complete.cases(df$A, df$D), ]
#     A   B     C   D
# 1 432  15 54654 432
# 2 321  NA  4534 324
# 3 123 432  6543  75
```

Using `subset()`:

```r
subset(df, complete.cases(A, D))
#     A   B     C   D
# 1 432  15 54654 432
# 2 321  NA  4534 324
# 3 123 432  6543  75
```

Here are a couple of other options using the **tidyverse**.

Using `drop_na()` from `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  drop_na(A, D)
#     A   B     C   D
# 1 432  15 54654 432
# 2 321  NA  4534 324
# 3 123 432  6543  75
```

Using `complete.cases()` with `filter()` from `dplyr` (this one is actually my preference for readability):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(A, D))
#     A   B     C   D
# 1 432  15 54654 432
# 2 321  NA  4534 324
# 3 123 432  6543  75
```

---

**Data**:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(23, 432, NA, 321, NA, 123),
                 B = c(NA, 15, NA, NA, 32, 432),
                 C = c(NA, 54654, NA, 4534, NA, 6543),
                 D = c(NA, 432, 654, 324, 643, 75))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(col1=c(1, NA, 7), col2=c(NA, 2, 5))

#   col1 col2
# 1    1   NA
# 2   NA    2
# 3    7    5



df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(col1) & !is.na(col2))
# 
#   col1 col2
# 1    7    5
```

Comment: If you are going tidyverse, it is probably worth noting `df %>% drop_na(A, D)` (from `tidyr` for those keeping track).

Comment: @Adam I wasn't aware of that tidy function, it's a lot cleaner than what I have. I see you have answered this question, but you didn't include the tidyr solution. There are many ways to achieve what the OP wants, but IMO the tidyr way you provide looks the simplest.

Comment: I'll add it into mine. I actually prefer `filter(df, complete.cases(A, D))` because when I see drop I think of dropping columns not filtering values, but much of this is preference.

Answer (score 0):

To only get the values you can simply:

```
(df$A / df$D)[!is.na(df$A / df$D)]
[1] 1.0000000 0.9907407 1.6400000
```

This puts the values as an additional column:

```
cbind( df, df$A / df$D )
    A   B     C   D df$A/df$D
1  23  NA    NA  NA        NA
2 432  15 54654 432 1.0000000
3  NA  NA    NA 654        NA
4 321  NA  4534 324 0.9907407
5  NA  32    NA 643        NA
6 123 432  6543  75 1.6400000
```